# Limit the text in table data in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

This is my code.

```
<tr>
<td>
{{ message }}
</td>
</tr>
```

In the message variable i have a large string. I want to display only some words or charecters. How can I limit them?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of one way to achieve what you are looking for, use the substring function to display just a portion of the message string. Replace length below with how many characters you want to limit the message string to.

```
<tr>
<td>
{{ message.substring(0, length) }}
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: substring is a standard js function to make one string from another. 0 is the start position, length can be substituted for a number that represents how many characters total to limit the string to.

Comment: @Stradosphere To add more information to your answer, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your answer instead of posting a comment, thanks :)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.